# How to get a handle/reference to the current controller object inside a rails functional test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I must be missing something very simple, but can't find the answer to this. I have a method named `foo` inside `bar_controller`. I simply want to call that method from inside a functional test.

Here's my controller:

```
class BarsController < ApplicationController
  def foo
    # does stuff
  end
end
```

Here's my functional test:

```
class BarsControllerTest << ActionController::TestCase
  def "test foo" do
    # run foo
    foo
    # assert stuff
  end
end
```

When I run the test I get:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for #<BarsControllerTest:0x102f2eab0>
```

All the documentation on functional tests describe how to simulate a http get request to the bar_controller which then runs the method. But I'd just like to run the method without hitting it with an http get or post request. Is that possible?

There must be a reference to the controller object inside the functional test, but I'm still learning ruby and rails so need some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in "Agile Web Development with Rails" Book. ActionController::TestCase initializes three instance variables needed by every functional test: @controller (contains instance of controller under test), @request, and @response.

Answer (score 0):

You need call this action with HTTP verb like

```
get :foo
post :foo
```

etc...

Comment: ahh, I think I understand now. I'm coming from a java background. So, I'm guessing controllers are like servlets? Typcially server containers instantiate servlets and similarly the rails server instantiates controllers so they have to be accessed via http.

Comment: the ControllerTest wrap the object in Rails Stack. You it's like you made this request. After you have request and response object.

Comment: hi shingara, I was able to get a hold of the controller instance using @controller. Thanks for your help.